# Explain Keychain plugin iOS (Cordova)

Tags: ios, cordova, keychain

I have vague idea on keychain that it is used for password management for ios. As proper documentation about it are not available I am coming here to you for help.
Can anybody clarify the purpose of getForKey() command?

Comment: There is proper documentation: [Keychain Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html). Also `getForKey()` does not seem to be anything related to iOS, are you using another framework the Apples own iOS SDK? Like Phonegep?

Comment: tag it with the correct language plz :)

Comment: @rckoenes: Hey I am using phonegap. getForKey() is the method in Keychain utility. But I am not finding proper documentation for it.

Comment: @Daij-Djan:Hey Daij I am using Phonegap mobile development framework. Keychain utility works only for apple iOS, macOSX.

Comment: Then edit your question and add the PhoneGap tag. No nobody knew you are talking about phone gap.

Answer (score 2):

Here, you have an easy to understand example. I focused on the Get function and left out the set and remove callback - as they are not needed if you understand GetSuccess callback.

First we set a key named **coins** to **600**, then we retrieve(get) that key, which triggers our `GetSuccess` callback, passes the value and should fire an alert.

```
// init
   var kc = new Keychain();
// Set key
    kc.setForKey(SetSuccess, failure, 'coins', 'servicename', '600');
// Get key
    kc.getForKey(GetSuccess, failure, 'coins', 'servicename');

// Get Success Callback
    function GetSuccess(value) {
            alert("GET SUCCESS - Coins Value: " + value);
        };

// Delete key
    kc.removeForKey(RemoveSuccess, failure, 'coins', 'servicename');

[...]
```

If you have any questions, ask.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using Shazron Abdullah's [Keychain Plugin](https://github.com/shazron/KeychainPlugin). If so, the API is very straightforward but the documentation can be a little confusing at first. The API relies on asynchronous callbacks, so you need to plan your code accordingly.

The parameters of `getForKey` are a success callback, a failure callback, a key name and a service name. I provide the name of my app as the service name.

Here's a small sample that should get you started (assuming that the plugin is installed):

```
(function(){
    // Create a new keychain object...
    var keychain = new window.Keychain();

    // Assign the value 'mysecret' to 'mykey'...
    keychain.setForKey(function() {
        console.log('key set succeeded');
        // Retrieve the value for 'mykey' and output to the console...
        keychain.getForKey(function(value) {
            console.log('key get, value = ' + value);
        }, function() {
            console.log('key get failed');
        }, 'mykey', 'myservice');
    }, function() {
        console.log('key set failed');
    }, 'mykey', 'myservice', 'mysecret');
})();
```

If your app has the plugin and is running on the iOS Simulator, you can open Safari's debug window and paste this code in for a quick demo.

Comment: In the github example I don't understand the sense and need for "servicename" in the setForKey/getForKey/removeForKey functions. Can you explain that?

Comment: "servicename" is an attribute for grouping related keys together. For example, your application name could be used for "servicename". Note that keychain item attributes are not encrypted.

Comment: @sherb That's not true. Keychain items are encrypted if `kSecAttr`is used.

Comment: @FlyingLemon do you have a reference? According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH204-TPXREF10), "The attributes are not encrypted, however, and can be read at any time, even when the keychain is locked." `kSecAttr` appears to be the prefix for keychain attributes, not an attribute itself, e.g. `kSecAttrAccount`, `kSecAttrService`, et cetera.

Comment: @sherb I read the docu, I think the phrase you quoted was referring to OS X keychain, iOS keychain is always encrypted. "A keychain is an encrypted container[...]", "The system generates its own password for the keychain, and stores the key on the device[...]"

Comment: The plugin's official example on github does not work for me. It does not mention that the Keychain object is a member of the window object. So, thanks for the help.

Comment: I can't get this plugin to install.